# I want to access one variable defined in one csh script to another csh script. How to implement in c-shell?

Tags: csh

Script 1:

```
#!bin/csh
set option = $<

switch ($option)
case 1 : ...
breaksw
case 2 : ...
breaksw
endsw
```

---

script 2 :

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Now how to access "option: variable defined in script 1 , so that based on option content , i would write if-elseif condition ?

Comment: If your two scripts can be launched *script1 | script2* then echo in the first and read in the second. If it cannot be envisaged then I believe that setting *$option* as an environment variable (*setenv*) in the first script, will be the most easy way to follow.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two scripts? Does one call the other, start it asynchronously, pipe to it? Do they even run at the same time, or on the same machine?

Comment: Call `script2` from inside `script1` and place the `$option` shell variable on the scrpt2's argument list.